# Intellij not showing external libraries besides JDK

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've encountered this problem where External Libraries show only JDK. All my imports are marked in red. I've tried the following:

- Invalidate cache /restart
- mvn clean install -DskipTests -> maven reload

But the libraries still won't load. What should I do?

Comment: So you listed all your dependencies as `<dependency>` in the ´pom.xml` ?

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?